# Convert Dataframe.describe output to some json

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, flask

I am learning Pandas + Python.

When I use `var = dataFrame.describe()` , I want the output to be converted to json, so that I can send it as a response via a Flask API

```
    order_id  quantity
count  5.000000  5.000000
mean   1.200000  1.200000
std    0.447214  0.447214
min    1.000000  1.000000
25%    1.000000  1.000000
50%    1.000000  1.000000
75%    1.000000  1.000000
max    2.000000  2.000000
```

Comment: `describe` returns a data frame obj, you can just use `var.to_json()` directly

Answer (score 4):

Use [DataFrame.to_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html):

```
var.to_json()
```

Output:

```
'{"order_id":{"count":5.0,"mean":1.2,"std":0.447214,"min":1.0,"25%":1.0,"50%":1.0,"75%":1.0,"max":2.0},"quantity":{"count":5.0,"mean":1.2,"std":0.447214,"min":1.0,"25%":1.0,"50%":1.0,"75%":1.0,"max":2.0}}'
```